# Simulink to Raspberry Pi error: Undefined function

Tags: matlab, raspberry-pi, simulink

I am trying to deploy a Simulink model to Raspberry Pi. The model contains a constant value of 2 in the format of `uint8`, which is sent over UDP. When I try to deploy this model, I get the following error:

> Undefined function 'execute' for input arguments of type 'double'.

What am I doing wrong? I have created a folder in RP and have specified the the folder in the deployment settings. Can't think of anything

Comment: We cannot help you without a functioning example that reproduces your issue and the *full* error message, not your paraphrasing.

Comment: Have you installed [Support for Raspberry Pi Hardware](http://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/raspberrypi/ug/install-target-for-raspberry-pi-hardware.html) and gone through the [tutorial](http://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/raspberrypi/examples/getting-started-with-raspberry-pi-hardware.html)?

Comment: I have installed the support package and I have followed precisely all the steps that are shown in a tutorial video where RP is installed from scratch: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3ZpB0SfbNA). What I have quoted is all that the actual error message says.

Comment: Normally this error appears if the function you are calling can not be found in memory e.g. because the *toolbox is not installed or the path is not correctly set* (see http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100888-why-do-i-receive-an-undefined-function-or-variable-error-when-trying-to-use-a-built-in-function-of )

Comment: See also this link http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/247999-problem-with-undefined-function-or-variable-raspi

Comment: I have created a folder in RP and added that location to the Simulink deploy settings. Also I am only using a constant and a Raspberry Pi UDP Receive block(came withthe Ra_Pi support package for Simulink). The model does not create an error when I run it in Simulink.

Comment: If you are on linux disable the ufw firewall. It blocks all UDP packets. How is your function *execute* defined ?

Comment: Simulink is running on Windows 8 and the Pi has Raspbian. Could you explain what you mean by: " How is your function execute defined ?"

Comment: That's all the error message says? There's *nothing* else displayed in the command window?

Comment: is the function *execute* written in C i.e. `int execute(double y){}` or is it inbuilt in simulink ?

Comment: @ralfhtp: `execute` is a [method of the `raspberrypi` class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/raspberrypi/examples/remote-execution-of-linux-commands.html).

Comment: See this tutorial https://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/how-to-use-matlab-and-simulink-with-raspberry-pi.pdf and try if you can replicate the example in it.

Comment: I have the model in simulink. I go to "run on target hardware->prepare to run" there I choose Rasp-Pi as hardware implementation. I also set the build directory. Then I press  "apply" and "ok", close the window and above my model I press build.

Comment: If you deploy the simple example model in the tutorial  https://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/how-to-use-matlab-and-simulink-with-raspberry-pi.pdf you can see if deployment in general is not working or if only the deployment of your model in particular is not working. It seems that the error is somewhere in the model you use (what are you doing with the constant and the udp receive block ?). Try  to deploy the example model in the tutorial this only takes 10 min

Comment: Did you name your model `rpi` or `raspberrypi`? This might cause a name-conflict with the functions from the support package.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help, but figured it out on my own. I had a static IP assigned to